# VSCode auto import node modules-How to display `import A from "moduleName"` rather than `import A = require("moduleName")`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

VSCode auto import node modules:
How to display `import A from "moduleName"` rather than `import A = require("moduleName")`?

Comment: Have you tried [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript)? This may help, give a try.

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti   I had, with no luck though. I suspect this was a bug of vscode itself, cuz having searched lots of related materials and tried almost all the related settings.    
I've posted this on [vscode github issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/69888).
Anyway, thanks.